# if statement show image in cell

Tags: json, uitableview, uiimage

I would like to show a image in my cell, but only if the value of the `JSON` data is 1 (only 0 or 1 possible)
Maybe also if the value of the `JSON` data is 0 show different image, so each cell can show 2 different images.
The problem so far is that the cell contains the image, no mather what the value of the `JSON` data is.

**Code so far:**

```
NSArray *arrayOfEntry = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"notities"];
for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfEntry) 
{
    sonResults = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"notities"];
    NSMutableString *checkvink = [diction objectForKey:@"not_verwerkt"];

    if(![checkvink isEqual: @"1"])
    {
           NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vink" ofType:@"png"];
           imageData = [NSData dataWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]]; 
    } 
}
```

then I show the image like this

```
UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
cell.notAfbeel.image = imageLoad;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: complete cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
        static NSString *Cellidentifier = @"Cell";

NotitieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier];

if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[NotitieCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Cellidentifier];
}

NSDictionary *appsdict = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

cell.notAfbeel.image = imageLoad;

return cell;
}
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
"notities": [{
    "not_nr": "1191555",
    "not_tijd": "12:29:54",
    "not_type": "0",
    "not_behandeld": "Richard",
    "not_bestemd": "Richard",
    "not_contactpers": "Maarten",
    "not_prioriteit": "1",
    "not_onderwerp": "Printer staat er nog steeds in",
    "not_naam": "apple store",
    "not_woonpl": "Amsterdam",
    "not_land": "NL",
    "not_verwerkt": "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: post your Entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: posted cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: allocate the imageData in cellForRowAtIndexPath itself just before the statement "UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];"

Sorry for the delay dude

Comment: I'm a beginner, how do I do that?

Comment: Write your first piece of code exactly before the statement that I mentioned

Comment: then I see no image at all 'imageData = [[NSData alloc ]init];'is what I used

Comment: imageData = [NSData alloc]; did't work either

Comment: Have you tried placing the entire block? i.e--

NSArray *arrayOfEntry = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"notities"];
for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfEntry) 
{
    sonResults = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"notities"];
    NSMutableString *checkvink = [diction objectForKey:@"not_verwerkt"];

    if(![checkvink isEqual: @"1"])
    {
           NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vink" ofType:@"png"];
           imageData = [NSData dataWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]]; 
    } 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `imageData` is an instance variable. You are setting its value for the entire object instance, not just the cell. So, she the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, it is putting this variable value in all cells.

Transforming your `arrayOfEntry` in a property and assuming that it is fully displayed on your tableView, we could rewrite your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     static NSString *Cellidentifier = @"Cell";

     NotitieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier];

     if(!cell)
     {
         cell = [[NotitieCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Cellidentifier];
     }

     NSDictionary *appsdict = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSMutableString *checkvink = [[self.arrayOfEntry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"not_verwerkt"];

     NSData *imageData = nil; // local, now

     if(![checkvink isEqualToString: @"1"])
     {
         NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vink" ofType:@"png"];
         imageData = [NSData dataWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]];
     }

     UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

     cell.notAfbeel.image = imageLoad;

     return cell;
  }
```

Maybe it is not the best answer according to your data but is just to give you an idea so you can adapt it.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me! sorry for the late response (the flu got me). I removed self. because I already said that earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `isEqualToString` instead of `isEqual`, since you're comparing NSString values at the line:

```
if(![checkvink isEqualToString: @"1"])
```

Comment: hummm... could you post part of your JSON file, @SpeedfreakR ? maybe this will help a little

Comment: JSON is not the problem (I guess because I can show labels with the JSON data, but I will post it.

Comment: I think the problem is that imageData is a instance variable. You are setting its value for the entire object, not for each cell.. so, when the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is called, it is getting this variable value to all cells... you should find a way to put that verification inside the "cellForRowAtIndexPath"